# Link an image to a cell with phpspreedsheet

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

I am using code this code to add images in column and cell.

```
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0 , 0 , 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
$draw->setName($itmref[$key]);
$draw->setResizeProportional(false);
$draw->setImageResource($image_p);
$draw->setRenderingFunction(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_JPEG);
$draw->setMimeType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);
$draw->setCoordinates('B'.$i);
$draw->setWorksheet($this->_spreadsheet->getActiveSheet());
```

The problem is that they are not linked to the cell so if the user filters or sorts the Excel file, the images remain in their position.

In VBA the parameter is:

```
Selection.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
```

But I can't find a match in PhpSpreedSheet.